# Is it ok to use Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() in uwp?

Tags: uwp

I have used 'Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()' to find the exe path, to find some images folder stored in a shared Class Library project. I am able to successfully run this project in my pc, while testing in visual studio.

The 'Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()' gets the exe path, I use this path to get the Shared Images folder path. Everything works fine. But after I create packages to upload to store, the app crashes, WACK fails with various errors, few of them are 'Platform version launch', 'App launch', '
Crashes and hangs' etc.

I suspect, whether the 'Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()' method/api is the problematic one.
But Microsoft has documented about this as a part of uwp, as mentioned here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory?view=netcore-3.1

Where am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated. I am unable to step forward.

Extra info: If I launch the 'Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()' folder, the following folder is launched.

[image]

Comment: Hello, in UWP, `StorageFolder` is usually used instead of `Directory`. Although `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` can be used in UWP, it returns the path of the folder. If you want to access files or folders by path, this is restricted behavior in UWP. You mentioned that you cannot pass the WACK check. What did you do after obtaining the folder path? You can describe your purpose, maybe there are other solutions.

Comment: Yes, If it is a StorageFolder, it won't have any issues. Here what I do is, I have some image folders inside the 'SharedLibrary' shared Class Library project. I display those images to the user, when he browses the app. I know, that these folders can be copied to the app's localfolder, then display them. But I want to know about this Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() method, since it works during testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to display the static image resources in the class library, we do not need to copy the image to the application folder, nor obtain the image through the path. UWP provides a relatively simple solution.

we can put the image in the `Assets` folder in the class library (such as `SharedLibrary/Assets/test.png`), and set the `Build Action` to **Content**, and `Copy to the output directory` as **False**.

After ensuring that the main project references this class library, you can get the picture through the uri scheme of `ms-appx`:

**Xaml**

```xml
<Image Source="ms-appx:///SharedLibrary/Assets/test.png"/>
```

**C#**

```cs
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///SharedLibrary/Assets/test.png"));
MyImage.Source = bitmap;
```

**Get the image file**

```cs
var imgFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///SharedLibrary/Assets/test.png"));
```